# How to read Environment Properties set in AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: linux, spring, amazon-web-services

I have set environment properties in elasticbeanstalk, Property Name: `spring.profiles.active`, Property Value: `qa`.

[image]

On spring application deploy this value is correctly read by using `ps -aef | grep tomcat` from terminal.

[image]

I want to be able to read this environment property in a shell script and extract the value "qa" which I use to configure other items on the server.

Is this possible and if so, how do I do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I found out how to get the result I was looking for.

Here is the command:

```
ps -aef | grep tomcat | grep -Po 'spring.profiles.active=\K[^ ]+'
```

If someone has a cleaner or better way of doing this I will gladly accept it.

G